# How to debug some complex c++ stls in watches of CodeBlocks? E.G. vector<vector<int> >v

Tags: c++, debugging, stl, codeblocks

I wrote a simple program concerning c++ stls. But I found that using CodeBlocks is very hard to debug with some kinds of a little more complex stls E.G. vector<vector >v. When I debug the program below with CodeBlocks, the watch of "v" looks like the picture below. However, I can watch vectorv1 and v2 just fine, which seems puzzling to me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector<vector<int> >v;
vector<int>v1 = { 1,2,3 };
vector<int>v2 = { 4,5,6 };
int main()
{
    v.push_back(v1);
    v.push_back(v2);
    return 0;
}
```

[image: picture of the watches in CodeBlocks]

I'm using the default compiler and debugger of CodeBlocks.The standard is C++11.
P.S. In certain c++ competitions, all I can use is CodeBlocks and DevC++, and maybe VSCode. Visual Studio and Clion are not permitted in the match.

Comment: Back in ancient times, when dinosaurs roamed the Earth, aspiring C++ uberhackers used basic, elementary, command line debuggers like `gdb` to learn how to debug their code. Crude, compared to modern debuggers with flashy icons, eye-popping windows, and animated paperclips. But the insights gained from that experience, and a complete understanding of the guts of their debuggers, have served them well in the years that followed. Both `v`, `v1`, and `v2` look alike to my eye, in the attached image. The question is unclear.

Comment: Sidenote: _"stls"_ isn't a thing. Perhaps you meant _standard library containers_?

Comment: @Sam Your other complaints aside - the display of vector `v` looks broken to me too.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Thx for your comment. What I want to express is I can clearly see the elements of vector<int>v1, but I can't see the elements within vector<vector<int> >v. All I can see is the length and capacity of v. I'll put it this way. Where can I see the content of v1-{1,2,3}  in the watch of "v"? I just can't find it. Meanwhile, there shouldn't be a v[2], because there are only 2 elements in "v", which are v1 and v2. In the picture, there is a v[2], which is not quite right.

Comment: Hm. Probably because, I bet, Code Blocks runs `gdb`, or similar, underneath the scenes and attemps to parse its output, in order to format it as a pretty table in a dialog, and throw in some animated paperclips for some entertainment. The more complex object breaks the parser, since it doesn't know how to handle the more complex object dump from the underlying debugger. Nothing much can be done about it. Except to learn how to use a basic, command line debugger, with plain text output that can be inspected directly, and is amenable to having a human's brain wrapped around it, fully.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik some of those "animated paperclips" can be productively useful. This example is small, but if there were 1000 elements of `v`, each with 1000 elements themselves, I'd want to be able to fold and unfold lines to look at the single entry that was vexing me, without millions of others getting in the way.

Comment: Does CodeBlocks allow you to watch (some restricted set of?) expressions, or just variables? If you can, then a workaround would be to watch `v[0]` and `v[1]`

Comment: I would switch to VSC. It takes a lot of effort to maintain an IDE, and I always got the impression that CB suffers from the lack of developers.

Comment: @Caleth It worked!!Thx. I simply add two lines to my code" vector<int> a = v[0];
    vector<int> b = v[1];" and watch a and b instead of v as a whole. It's still not very convenient, but at least It works right now.

Comment: @fruitshell that's not what I meant. Don't change your code, ask CodeBlocks to watch the expression `v[0]`

Comment: @Caleth Thx a lot for your help. I tried to add "v[0]" to watches in CodeBlocks, but it didn't show me anything and the debugger collapsed, quite a puzzle lol.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Hi there my friend, could you tell me what compiler are you using in VSCode?

Comment: You could use any compiler with it, it doesn't matter. I'm using Clang, because it's the best thing right now IMO, but you could use it with CB as well.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, in the screenshot you attached, the elements of V can be seen! 
V does not contain integers, but it contains vectors of integers. 
If you want to print the contents you can add the following code (after v.push_back(v2);):

```
for(auto row: v)
{
    for(auto elem: row)
    {
        cout << elem << "  ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```